# Notepad++ Merge list

Tags: notepad++

**List 1**

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
```

**List 2**

```
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

**Result**

```
text1=value1
text2=value2
text3=value3
text4=value4
```

How do I do this in Notepad++?

Comment: Where do these lists come from? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follows my solution.

First, concatenate the two lists separating them by a special character (in the following, I will use `§`):

```
text1
text2
text3
text4
§
value1
value2
value3
value4
```

Then:

1. Find what: `^(?!§$)(?!.*=)(.*)([\w\W]*?^§\r?\n)(.*)\r?\n?`
2. Replace with: `$1=$3$2`
3. Ensure to have the following settings:

[image: Screenshot]

4. Click as many times as needed on the `Replace` key.
5. Finally remove the special character.

Comment: Well this is a solution if you have small number of lines, but how about thousands of lines?